# Data export from VB.Net to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I  have created a dataset from xml file in VB.Net, which has several tables within it (which I can see by quickwatch function).

I want to transfer this dataset with multiple tables to SQL server into a new database.

I have created a connection between vb.net & sql server, but not able to transfer my dataset from vb.net to sql server (to create a database in sql server.

my data in xml:

````
<DESCRIBE> AXX RIGID INDENTATION DATA </DESCRIBE>
<EXPORT Date="2001-01-12" Time="13:00:00"/>
<Node AdjustDate="2001-01-12" Name="XBXX5" Type="AXX" TAG="">
<Experiment BuildingPractice="XYC511">
<Cabinet Position="">
 <Subrack Value="1.1.0.3" NAAM="EWXR2 40" Position="">
   <Sackxlanx NAAM="EXER2 40G BP">
     <Product FirstDate="2011-01-12" LastDate="2011-02-12" VAR1="20100811" ProductNAAM="EXEM3 40R BP" ProductDIGIT="XXJC0X3211/6" ProductYAAD="R2A" SerialNumber="XXXX77X33" Supplier="Random AB"/>
   </Sackxlanx>
   <PFM Name="PANKHA UNIT" PfmDeviceType="DOX" PfmHwVersion="1" PfmInstance="upper">
     <Product FirstDate="2011-01-12" LastDate="2011-01-12" VAR1="20100811" ProductNAAM="PANKHA UNIT" ProductDIGIT="XXXXXX3/1" ProductYAAD="X11B" SerialNumber="XX56977XX1" Supplier="Random AB"/>
   </PFM>
   <PFM Name="PANKHA UNIT" PfmDeviceType="SOD" PfmHwVersion="1" PfmInstance="lower">
     <Product FirstDate="2011-01-01" LastDate="2011-04-02" VAR1="20150704" ProductNAAM="PANKHA UNIT" ProductNumber="XXX14013/1" ProductYAAD="R11B" SerialNumber="X052916308" Supplier="Random AB"/>
   </PFM>
   <Board Comment="1.1.3.4" NAAM="EXX1" SlXXPositiXn="1">
     <Product FirstDate="2016-05-18" LastDate="2018-07-23" VAR1="20121004" ProductNAAM="EXX1" ProductDigit="XXX208394/2" ProductYAAD="XXD" SerialNumber="XXXXXG8615" Supplier="Random AB"/>
   </Board>
   </Subrack>
  </Cabinet>
</Experiment>
</Node> ```

**snippet of my code**:

Dim strOP As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strInput, pattern, "$1")

         Dim reader As New IO.StringReader(strOP)
         Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
         ds2.ReadXml(reader)
         TextBox1.Text = ds2.Tables.Count.ToString

         'Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter
         'Dim SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server =name\SQLEXPRESS; Database =SQLApps; Trusted_Connection = yes;"}
         'Dim SQLCmd As SqlCommand
         'SQLCon = New SqlConnection()
         'SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("", SQLCon)
         'adp = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
         'adp.Update(ds2)

         Dim connetionString As String
         Dim connection As SqlConnection
         Dim command As SqlCommand
         Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
         Dim ds As New DataSet
         Dim i As Integer
         Dim firstSql As String
         Dim secondSql As String

         connetionString = "Server =servername\SQLEXPRESS; Database =SQLApps; Trusted_Connection = yes;"
         firstSql = "select Description from NetInventory"
         secondSql = "select * from NetInventory"
         connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)


         connection.Open()

         command = New SqlCommand(firstSql, connection)
         adapter.SelectCommand = command
         adapter.Fill(ds2, "First Table")

         adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = secondSql
         adapter.Fill(ds2, "Second Table")

         adapter.Dispose()
         command.Dispose()
         connection.Close()

         'retrieve first table data
         For i = 0 To ds2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
             MsgBox(ds2.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0) & "  --  " & ds2.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
         Next
         'retrieve second table data
         For i = 0 To ds2.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
             MsgBox(ds2.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item(0) & "  --  " & ds2.Tables(1).Rows(i).Item(1))
         Next

     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
     End Try
     'Catch ex As Exception
     'End Try
 End Sub
End Class
````

Comment: You aren't transferring the data to SSMS, you're transferring it to SQL Server; SSMS is simply a user application for interacting with SQL Server is dosen't "hold" any data. What attempts have you made so far to get your data into SQL Server? You state *"Data export from VB.NET to SQL Server"*, which implies you tried *something*. Where did you get stuck, or what errors did you encounter? What does your data look like (you've omitted that from you post) and what is the definition of the table you have that you want to insert into. At the moment this is too vague to answer.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated my post with sample data and snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use sqlbulkcopy to completely transfer the datatables into sql server database tables?